what loss function can be used on incidence matrices of hypergraphs?
I am trying to minimize (optimize)  the distance between a generated subject-specific hypergraph and another set of hypergraphs (represents another set of random subjects), what kind of loss function can I use on incidence matrices knowing that each matrix is composed of columns that represent hyperedges and rows that represent nodes and each each hypergraph represents a subject where the entries are binary.

Please clarify your inputs and expected output. Give a small representative example if possible. As is, it's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

my inputs are a set of subjects, each represented by a hypergraph ( rooted in an incidence matrix). I feed each matrix with the corresponding node feature attributes to a hypergraph neural network (HGNN) to obtain a new embedding. This embedding is then converted to a hypergraph that I want to evaluate its representativeness with a random set of the initial input. In other words, I would like to optimize the difference between the obtained hypergraph (from the neural network) and a set of hypergraphs of the input subjects.
